# Orphaned $firebase references causing memory leak

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an angular service that creates synced $firebase references. These references are ultimately passed into a controller, and then to a directive with an isolate scope.

When the $scope of the controller is destroyed by navigating to a different state, the references appear to stay in memory and never get GCed.

**Code Sample:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ui.router']);

app.service('service', function($firebase) {

  var ref = new Firebase('https://ease-bugreport.firebaseio.com/tasks');

  return {
    find: function(taskId) {
      // Creating orphan refs after states are changed. Not getting $destroy()-ed as the corresponding scope is destroyed?
      return $firebase(ref.child(taskId)).$asObject();
    }
  }

});

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, service) {

  $scope.tasks = [];

  /*
      * In the real application, this list of ids is grabbed from an index of ids.
      */
  var taskIds = [
    '-JVMmByyk5wvYdVJQ_JT',
    '-JVMmBz4hue-5QytQwWb',
    '-JVMmBz8aAt5WDUQ4H1R',
    '-JVMmC-Q8QEGB6zZuitb',
    '-JVMmC-UkMAiyi6v6bcK',
    '-JVMmC-WyOrlNKZTjnqH',
    '-JVMmC-Y29ncf14G1rkA',
    '-JVMmC0coVLi1FUfrbKD',
    '-JVMmC1hDrs07XdwcgLh',
    '-JVMmC1k-GYz_DWw3dDj',
    '-JVMmC2aCuzOIZ2nf1B-',
    '-JVMmC2cQKNkOBxhJ5vP',
    '-JVMmC2giV_IlXrKXVFw',
    '-JVMmC3fXQYfjtXdTk_p',
    '-JVMmC3ibcUPT88hcD6Q',
    '-JVMmC3mDKms0BVpAcdq',
    '-JVMmC4jFwfPNe1-istd',
    '-JVMmC4m3ZGAiS7xnXHP',
    '-JVMmC4rp3pNfeTgIUCJ',
    '-JVMmC4uaH7MdkTZbQVm',
    '-JVMmC5ttFy3ojD1bt3t',
    '-JVMmC5v_iTwWS02PF9h',
    '-JVMmC5xFYPS0zvaU4bi',
    '-JVMmC75NA1H1e7dYGdM',
    '-JVMmC77o5mBUACibaUG',
    '-JVMmC7AmuYy6VDNn9B1',
    '-JVMmC85nVa6NexPJLLP',
    '-JVMmC88XIFUqq98gexw',
    '-JVMmC89h4HLaXxmHld8',
    '-JVMmC8CNJ55Olt8D57w'
  ];

  angular.forEach(taskIds, function(taskId) {
    $scope.tasks.push(service.find(taskId));
  });

});

app.directive('taskPanel', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      task: '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div>{{task.name}} - {{task.createdAt | date}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    }
  };

});

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    controller: function() {},
    template: '<div>MAIN PAGE!</div>'
  })
  .state('list', {
    url: '/list',
    controller: 'ctrl',
    templateUrl: 'list.html' 
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');

});
```

**Here is a codepen demonstrating the issue:** http://codepen.io/rabhw/pen/ADiKz

The issue is far more exaggerated in my application as each reference is using the 'objectFactory' option to attach additional instance methods via a factory.

Should I be taking a different approach to my services?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Your service is in no way connected to a scope. There is no scope passed into $firebase(...).$asObject(...). Can you explain how you would expect it, therefore, to automatically call $destroy when your scope is destroyed? Also, if those are getting re-used across controllers, why don't you have the logic that puts the various tasks into an array in the service so that it's only called once? Furthermore, if you want to keep that logic in the controller, why is there no attempt to call $destroy there?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following code to your controller:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.tasks = undefined; // or []
});
```

Should automatically be recognized in directive's `task`.